# Android room DB: Why do I get FOREIGN KEY constraint failed, even though I am inserting in the correct order?

Tags: android, sql, android-room

**EDIT:** problem was having multiple databases for entities. When I placed all the entities into one db, the code started working.

I am writing an Android app to manage orienteering competitions and I store the data in Room DB. I have multiple entities referencing the main entity Event via a foreign key, so if an Event is deleted, all of its data is deleted as well.

The problem is I still keep getting the error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)

whenever I try to insert a new category/competitor.

I made sure that the event was in the db, so the insert shouldn't cause any inconsistency in the database.

I did the following, nothing worked (except removing the foreign keys):

1. Checked the correct names on the entities
2. Verified that event is inserted first and the UUID exists in the DB
3. Tried changing some of the column names

I added the foreign keys recently, before (without them) everything was running fine, when I queried categories / competitors for an event.id, I got the correct results. I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any of the previous solutions on stack or other pages did not help.

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Thanks

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "event"
)
@TypeConverters(DateTimeTypeConverter::class)
data class Event(
    @PrimaryKey var id: UUID,
    var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: LocalDate,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "start_time") var startTime: LocalTime,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_type") var eventType: EventType,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_level") var eventLevel: EventLevel,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_band") var eventBand: EventBand,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "time_limit") var timeLimit: Duration
) : Serializable
```

My category class (one of the classes having event as a foreign key).

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "category", indices = [Index(
        value = ["name", "event_id"],
        unique = true
    )],
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Event::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("event_id"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
@TypeConverters(DateTimeTypeConverter::class)
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey var id: UUID,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_id") var eventId: UUID,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "age_based") var ageBased: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "min_year") var minYear: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "max_year") var maxYear: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "different") var differentProperties: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_type") var eventType: EventType,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "limit") var timeLimit: Duration,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cp_names") var controlPointsNames: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cp_codes") var controlPointsCodes: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "length") var length: Float,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "climb") var climb: Float,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "order") var order: Int
) : Serializable
```

My competitor class

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "competitor",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Category::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("category_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL,

            ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Event::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("event_id"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )]
)
data class Competitor(
    @PrimaryKey var id: UUID,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "event_id") var eventId: UUID,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id") var categoryId: UUID? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") var firstName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") var lastName: String,
    var club: String,
    var index: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_woman") var isWoman: Boolean = false,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "birth_year") var birthYear: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "si_number") var siNumber: Int? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "si_rent") var siRent: Boolean = false,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "default_start_time") var defaultStartTime: LocalTime? = null,
) : Serializable
```

My category insert method in the category DAO

```kotlin
@Insert
suspend fun createCategory(category: Category): Long
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help or not but try adding OnConflictStrategy at the time of inserting values.
Refer : `https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy`

Also just wanted to know if there is any particular reason for using UUID instead of using `(autoGenerated = true)` for the primary key

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, found that I had multiple databases which were causing the problem.

Comment: A Foreign Key conflict is not trapped/handled by ON ONCONFLICT as per *The ON CONFLICT algorithm does not apply to FOREIGN KEY constraints.* https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found that I did not try everything and I had multiple databases for my entities which caused the problem. Thanks for help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218620/23363460

> Everything you did seems to be pretty much okay, but you shouldn't have two separate databases for Playlist and Song. Instead, you should have only ONE database that contains two tables (Entities), which should be related to each other through a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT.